# Update an object (or get QuerySet from object) obtained with one-to-one relationship in django

Tags: django

I have a UserProfile model, I want to update the profile's points of a user.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')
    points = DecimalField(default=0)

User.profile = property(lambda u: UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])
```

I tried `User.objects.get(username='Joe').profile.update(points=100)` but it does not work since `User.objects.get(username='Joe').profile` is not a `QuerySet`.

How can I update the profile? Or how can I get a `QuerySet` instance out of `User.objects.get(username='Joe').profile`?

Comment: why do you want to update it as a queryset? can you not just do `User.objects.get(username='Joe').profile.points = 100` ? Its the same thing. Just that you have to call the `save` method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User.objects.get(username='Joe').profile actually returns a UserProfile object. Since a UserProfile object is not a queryset, it doesn't have the update() method.

You can either do:

```
try:
    userProfile = User.objects.get(username='Joe').profile
    userProfile.points = 100
    userProfile.save()
except UserProfile.DoesNotExist:
    pass
```

or to update using a queryset where the user's username equals 'Joe'

```
UserProfile.objects.filter(user__username='Joe').update(points=100)
```

Comment: Which one is the preferred way? fastest? The problem with the first method is that it loads the object in memory? Is the request optimized in the second method?

Comment: The second method is faster. The first method needs a try/except block in most cases, in case the user does not exist. I updated my code with try/except. See this link for try/except performance in python http://paltman.com/2008/01/18/try-except-performance-in-python-a-simple-test/.

Comment: But at the same time, the second method will fail silently if there are no users with the username 'Joe'. So if you need to know whether an update actually occurred you could check the length of the queryset, or use the first method